# cursor moves in range

Tags: normal-mode

I have this function that gets range.

From the help:

> The cursor is still moved to the first line of the            range, as is the
>   case with all Ex commands.

Can it not do it? I just want to get the count. It does so even if I don't specify range there.

```
function! InsertBefore() range
    if v:count==0
        let l=1
    else
        let l=v:count
    endif
    for j in range(l)
        let t=getchar()
        if t==27
            break
        endif
        exec ":\<c-U>normal a"."\<c-r>='".nr2char(t)."'"."\<ESC>"
        "redraw
    endfor 
endfunction
nmap = :call InsertBefore()<CR>
```

Comment: I don't quite get it. In Normal mode the first line of the range is always the current line.

Comment: BTW. If you don't need the range you should do something like `nnoremap <leader>a :<C-U>call MyFunction(v:count1)<CR>`

Comment: That is the answer. I expected the `<c-u>` to disable the range